# Change colour based on tags in Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

I'm trying to create a kind of IF statement using Tumblr tags.

Tumblr uses these shortcodes to output each post's tags:

> {block:Tags}{Tag}{/block:Tags}

...which would output this:

> "tag1tag2tag3tag4etc"

I would like to create something like...

If {block:tags}{tag}{block:tags} includes "red", return the hex for red. If it includes "blue", return the hex for blue, and if it returns "red", return red.

I'm guessing this will require javascript, which I've never used. This should be fairly simple though, and any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to color each tag with a certain color, or do you want to color the posts with a certain color if they have a certain tag?

Comment: `{TagsAsClasses}` can help you, `<article class="{TagsAsClasses}">...`